# Filter Data using GeoFire

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am working on an App which is showing drivers on map. I used GeoFire for that. In my app, I need to show only those drivers who are available.
Please see the attached image for better info.

[image]

if `"is_hired":"0" && "driver_available":"true"`, only then should drivers display on the map, else they are removed from the map.

Right now, its displaying all drivers because I don't know how to filter drivers using its data on Firebase.

With GeoFire, I need to create a different node for updating the driver location and it has its overridden methods:

```
@Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        Log.e("KEY","KEY-->> " + key);
        Log.e("Location","Location-->> " + location.latitude+","+location.longitude);
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Marker Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Add a new marker to the map
        Marker marker = this.googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)));
        this.driverMarkers.put(key, marker);
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyExited(String key) {
        // Remove any old marker
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Marker removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Marker marker = this.driverMarkers.get(key);
        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
            this.driverMarkers.remove(key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        // Move the marker
        Marker marker = this.driverMarkers.get(key);
        if (marker != null) {
            this.animateMarkerTo(marker, location.latitude, location.longitude);
        }
    }
```

How can I filter those markers who are not hired and available?

Before GeoFire, I was using Firebase database queries. Its drawback was it was fetching entire database drivers. I need to show only nearby drivers. 
Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to filter the drivers in the client inside `onKeyEntered` method.

```
@Override
public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
    ref.child("drivers").child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Driver driver = dataSnapshot.getValue(Driver.class);
            if (driver.getIs_hired().equals("0") && driver.getDriver_available().equals("true")) {
                Marker marker = this.googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)));
                this.driverMarkers.put(key, marker);
            }
        }

        ...
    });
}

...
```

BTW, I use the `equals` method because the value for `driver_available` and `is_hired` in your database is in `String`, you might want to change them to `Boolean` and `Integer`

Comment: Thanks buddy for saving my day. Its working fine, But i have another query.  Markers are getting filtered while adding, In case they are added and then is_hired change to 1 in Firebase DB then how can i get the event ? At that time location of driver is not changed, so on "onKeyMoved" method will not work.

Comment: to get the update, change the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to `addValueEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with @Willik's method is that it will download the whole list and as they mentioned filter client side. Instead you should be storing your data differently with an index that allows you to search faster:

```
{
    driver_available:"true",
    is_hired:"0",
    driver_available_is_hired: "true_0"
    ...
}
```

This is in general how firebase suggest storing data. Then you can do a query like:

```
.ref(...).orderByChild('driver_available_is_hired').equalTo('true_0')
```